# How do you save an image from a Three.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do you save an image from a Three.js canvas?

I'm attempting to use Canvas2Image but it doesn't like to play with Threejs. Since the canvas isn't defined until it has a div to attach the canvas object to.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/canvas2image-save-out-your-canvas-data-to-images

Comment: I'm not sure you can.  2D canvas supports this, but I _believe_ that a WebGL canvas does not.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Since the toDataURL is a method of canvas html element, that will work for 3d context too. But you have to take care of couple of things.

1. Make sure when the 3D context is initialized you set `preserveDrawingBuffer` flag to true, like so:

   ```
   var context = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
   ```
2. Then user `canvas.toDataURL()` to get the image

In threejs you would have to do the following when the renderer is instantiated:

```
new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true 
});
```

Also, keep in mind this can have performance implications. (Read: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/421#issuecomment-1792008)

This is **only for webgl renderer**, in case of threejs canvasRenderer though, you can simply do `renderer.domElement.toDataURL();` directly, no initialization parameter needed.

My webgl experiment: http://jsfiddle.net/TxcTr/3/ press '**p**' to screenshot.

Props to [gaitat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980846/gaitat), I just followed the link in his comment to get to this answer.

Comment: Dinesh, do you know if this would also work in nodejs too or not ?

Answer (score 39):

I read the conversation posted by Dinesh (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/421#issuecomment-1792008) and came up with a solution that won't slow down your application.

```
    function render() { 
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        if(getImageData == true){
            imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
            getImageData = false;
        }
    }
```

With this you can leave the preserveDrawingBuffer-Flag at false and still get the image from THREE.js. Simply set getImageData to true and call render() and you are good to go.

```
getImageData = true;
render();
console.debug(imgData);
```

Hope this helps people like me who need the high fps :)

Comment: Basically it turns out that with threejs you need 2 calls one after another:
renderer.render(scene, camera);
renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
In many cases the simplest approach may be just to put them in some seperate function outside of the normal rendering loop.

Comment: Use these settings to prevent having too much memory usage `.toDataURL( 'image/jpeg', 1.0 );` otherwise the imgData contains a raw image. It saved me from 12MB to 400Kb of space

Comment: I'm trying this version, but unfortunately I'm getting a black image. Does the render function in requestAnimationFrame call the function it is located in, or is this a render function provided by three (so renderer.render)?

Comment: @DSz it's been 6 years but if I remember correctly the render function is constantly calling itself to redraw (like games do for example) so animated objects or camera movement would show up on screen. This loop will check if it needs to genereate a "screenshot" everytime. Calling render() one additional time shouldn't have any impact on this loop. But again it has been 6 years. Chances are high you're using a newer version of three.js where things might be different.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering. I'll try exploring more how to solve it!

Comment: I'm also getting a black image with this method. @DSz did you get a way of doing this?

Comment: You need first to add "new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ preserveDrawingBuffer: true });" after creating the renderer on your code and then it will work

Answer (score -2):

use canvas to create the url, and then the same can be downloaded

```
function createImage(saveAsFileName) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var url = canvas.toDataURL();

    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('download', saveAsFileName);

    link.click();
}
```

Comment: On vanilla three.js this code actually only returns a black png image