# taking a 'snapshot' of babylonjs scene sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: html5-canvas, cloning, babylonjs

I am trying to take a 'snapshot' of a babylon3d scene ... in other words: I am trying to clone a babylon3d canvas when a user presses a button, and  then append the new `<canvas>` to the `<body>` .. Sometimes it works, but other times it does not.

However, if I use a simple canvas (ie. by using fillRect), the cloning/appending always works as expected.

I have set up a test on plunker to demonstrate my problem: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XmZ7ihawmSoTnOMSD7KF?p=preview): press the button over and over again to see how sporadic it behaves when there is a babylon scene. **AND NOTE**: You can toggle between the simple canvas and the babylon canvas from within the _jquery(document).ready(...)   handler.

```
thanks, Shannon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because from [version 2.3.0 of Babylonjs](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Documentation/blob/master/content/whats-new/whats-new.md) :

> Engine now initialize WebGL with preserveDrawingBuffer = false by default.

You need to initialize the Engine by passing a `{preserveDrawingBuffer: true}` object as third parameter.

**[Forked plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NNJdD0Iu7kJFZ3ZstD4j?p=preview)**

But this will unfortunately kill your canvas' performances.

[See more about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15558418/3702797)

I'm not really a specialist of Babylonjs, and I didn't find a way to make a call from `scene.render` method where we could use the flag method proposed by 
@CapsE. But there is a [`BABYLON.Tools.CreateScreenshot(engine, camera, size)`](http://doc.babylonjs.com/tutorials/Render_Scene_on_a_PNG) method, which will make a downloadable png from your scene ; maybe this could help you.