# How To get 2D Snapshot [like panoramic] of whole 3D Three.js Scene?

Tags: three.js, webgl

**How To get 2d Snapshot of Three.js 3D Scene ??
I need to get 2D Snapshot of my 3D scene like a panoramic image.(Full 360 snapshot)**

Demo Used:- http://patcat.com/demos/VRWeatherParticles/

I tried this solution :- 
1.**[How do you save an image from a Three.js canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558418/how-do-you-save-an-image-from-a-three-js-canvas)**
2. **[Three.js: How can I make a 2D SnapShot of a Scene as a JPG Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193702/three-js-how-can-i-make-a-2d-snapshot-of-a-scene-as-a-jpg-image)**

**When i do (what mentioned in Link 2)**:-

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
preserveDrawingBuffer: true
});

var strMime = "image/jpeg";
imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strMime);
imgData1 = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
```

I am getting the String base64, but i am not able to decode (used online tools [http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter]) it properly. Only **Black Image is coming up.**

Please let me know how to get :- 2D Snapshot of my 3d scene like a panoramic image.

NOTE:- [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193702/three-js-how-can-i-make-a-2d-snapshot-of-a-scene-as-a-jpg-image) should have worked, but it is not working for me.

Comment: This might be helpfu http://stackoverflow.com/a/26790802/128511 also if you want to convert it to a PNG you need to split at the comma as in `binary = someBase64ToBinaryFunction(dataUrl.split(",")[1])`;

Comment: Thankyou gman. This would help. Other part of my question is :-  To capture 360 Scene in 2D Image. Can you help me in this?

Comment: @kautuksahni: can you please create a jsfiddle or codepen sample?

Comment: I'm guessing this is what you want. https://github.com/spite/THREE.CubemapToEquirectangular

Comment: @gman Thank you, this is what i was looking for. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @gman Hi, is there a way by which i can map camera direction in 3D scene to 2d image generated from CubemapToEquirectangular? I mean, can we tell which part of 3D scene is in 2D image. Something like 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is suggested to me by [Gman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman) .
I am shearing it with community for their benefit.

"**CubemapToEquirectangular**" library helps as in getting panoramic image of 3D scene.

**Link**:- https://github.com/spite/THREE.CubemapToEquirectangular

**Demo Solution**:- https://www.clicktorelease.com/tools/CubemapToEquirectangular/index-managed.html

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni