# How to convert .stl files to .png using python ? And how to get its dimensions?

Tags: javascript, python, printing, 3d, three.js

I want to convert .stl files to .png for preview purpose, using Python.
Also, how can I get .stl file's dimensions, like volume and height and width?

To view the .stl files I use Three.js, but I am still not able to properly view the object, I want something which happens over here in [Astropint.com](https://www.astroprint.com) once we upload the file they directly show a .png file and that too in a proper manner. I saw this for using .stl files with python: python-stl but was unable to get anything from it. I am unable to get the dimensions of the .stl files like they do it over here : [View Stl online](http://www.viewstl.com/). Is there any Python based tool that I can use to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any one who stumbles on this in future, I did this with help of three.js itself. I was unable to find something similar in python. What I wanted was done with this : [How do you save an image from a Three.js canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558418/how-do-you-save-an-image-from-a-three-js-canvas)