# ThreeJS 3D drawing into manufacturing drawings

Tags: javascript, 3d, geometry

We've been dealing with the drawing blueprints with Three.JS. We want convert our 3D object into to the manufacturing bluepritns (TOP Orthogonal view on drawings) .

What we have:

[image: 3D object]

What we want to export:

[image: TOP Orthogonal view on drawings]

Does anybody dealt with that ? I cannot find workable solution on internet. We have been struggling with this for a long time :\

Answer (score 0):

You can just rotate your object and then download it from canvas:
[How do you save an image from a Three.js canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558418/how-do-you-save-an-image-from-a-three-js-canvas)

You can also change object type from full mesh into armature so that it becomes transparent.

Another option if you need some postprocessing is export your 3d object into blender (there are many exporter modules available).
Then in blender, write a script to create image in three projections you need.

I think you can automate this all quite quickly.

PD. If you need stl format exporter. Will this fit your need? 
https://threejs.org/examples/misc_exporter_stl.html

Comment: Thank you so much, but the problem is, we want to download STL format and then convert it do DWG / DXF for Manufacturing blueprints / drawings

Comment: We are able to download stl and convert it to the dxf and dwg, but we are not able to download only top orthogonal view as I posted in my question (images). We want to so this cause of manufacturing purpose